# How to write and retrieve data from ManyToManyField inside overrided save() method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I need to write any data to ManyToManyField via Model's form in the template, but i get an error like "... needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.". It shows when I try to use self.service("service" is my ManyToManyField) in my overrided save() method. I know that ManyToManyField is not basic field and it returns something like queryset, but how can i manipulate data inside save() method, because "self.service" doesn't work.

```
# models.py
class Appointments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Имя, фамилия')
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    e_mail = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='E-mail')
    car = models.ForeignKey('Cars', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Тип автомобиля')
    num_car = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Гос.номер автомобиля')
    **service = models.ManyToManyField(Services, verbose_name='Тип услуги')**
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Дата публикации заявки')
    date_service = models.DateField(db_index=True, verbose_name='Дата')
    time_service = models.TimeField(db_index=True, help_text="Введите время в таком формате: 15:00", verbose_name='Время')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, null=True, verbose_name='Цена')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i in Services_prices.objects.all():
            ccar = i.car
            sservice = i.service
               for d in self.service:
                    if self.car == ccar and d == sservice:
                        self.price = i.price
                        break
                    elif ccar == None and d == sservice:
                        self.price = i.price
                        break
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)



# forms.py
class AppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    service = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Services.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = Appointments
        fields = ('name', 'tel', 'e_mail', 'car', 'num_car', 'service', 'date_service', 'time_service')
```

Comment: Exactly why do you save the price on an appointment? What if there are multiple `Service`s?

Comment: I need just information about write and retrieve data with ManyToManyField. Multiple Services is my problem :) I will write any code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have a many_to_many relation between two objects, you need primary keys of the both objects. Before calling super's save, your model does not have a primary key yet.

In your overriden save method, call super first, (e.g.`super().save(*args, **kwargs)`) then do your stuff, then save again.

Comment: And how can I retrieve data from ManyToManyField? I tried "self.service.all().count()" and it returns 0.

Comment: Try self.services.all()

Comment: I tried that. But I need to realize how it works(and I'm not sure that It works). Code like "for d in self.service.all()" doesn't work. Therefore i tried to use count() and it returns 0.

Comment: Notice the 's'. Self.services.all() or self.service_set.all() i dont remember which one. Try both. Happy new year!

Comment: It's not working, but okay, I will be trying to do that. Thank you for your time. Happy New Year!